# django FileBrowseField shows as CharField

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I have downloaded django-filebrowser 3.4.3 (no grapelli) and all installation steps went OK.
However when I add a FileBrowseField in my model, it shows as a CharField. I don't want that!
It should show me a FileBrowseField

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from filebrowser.fields import FileBrowseField
class Logo(models.Model):
    logo = FileBrowseField(max_length=250)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from models import Logo

class LogoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['logo']
admin.site.register(Logo, LogoAdmin)
```

please help!!

Comment: What happens when you click on the charfield?

Comment: just normal CharField behaviour: i can type text

Comment: Under requirements here: https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser it says PIL and Grapelli are required. Are they installed?

Comment: PIL is installed, but I don't need grappelli, I've use this one: https://github.com/smacker/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli-django14

Comment: weird...
in `/templates/filebrowser/custom_field.html` second line has a hyperlink without any image or text associated with it:
`<input id="{{ final_attrs.id }}" type="text" class="vFileBrowseField" name="{{ final_attrs.name }}" value="{{ value.path }}" /><a href="javascript:FileBrowser.show('{{ final_attrs.id }}', '{{ url }}?pop=1{% if final_attrs.directory %}&amp;dir={{ final_attrs.directory|urlencode|urlencode }}{% endif %}{% if final_attrs.format %}&amp;type={{ final_attrs.format }}{% endif %}');" class="fb_show"></a>` When I put some text there, I can click the link and upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that I was missing an image in the `/static/filebrowser/img` folder. It's the image you click on to open the browser. I've added the image and linked to it from the correct template: `/templates/filebrowser/custom_field.html`